# You are missing the İmagick library for PHP. How install Imagick easily?

Tags: php, imagick

I am getting this error.

```
You are missing the `İmagick` library for PHP, install and activate it
```

I installed  `#yum install ImageMagick#` and `#yum install ImageMagick-devel#` but still same error appear.

How can I install `Imagick` easily.

Comment: you must take care on asking question, most of time if ebtter on irc for simple things. I understand you are new and you are looking for the fastest and best place for answer, and sure this is the best one, unfortunately there are people that thing taht all  people here must be experts in order to ask and been answered ( really unfortunatelly ) and give -1 on initial post ( disapointed people )

Comment: No problem Carlos, I tried many method for solve this but I cant install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ImageMagick is the distribution library, you have to now install php-imagick, or something along those lines for your distro.

Check PHP documentation, this can be done through PECL `sudo pecl install imagick`:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setup.php